# How Unpivot / Transpose some Columns in SQL BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have tried to Unpivot/Transpose some Columns of a table BigQuery using SQL. I would like to do everything in a single query.

I have tried diferent posibilities but didn´t get any working results.

=>Some elegant Ideas?

This are the tables:

**Source:**

| Date | Advertiser | Clicks | Conversion 1 | Conversion 2 | Conversion 3 | Conversion 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-23 | Advertiser AT | 3 | 0 | 0 | 75 | 0 |
| 2022-03-23 | Advertiser AT | 16 | 0 | 0 | 67 | 0 |
| 2022-03-20 | Advertiser AT | 32 | 0 | 0 | 58 | 0 |
| 2022-03-22 | Advertiser AT | 25 | 0 | 0 | 57 | 1 |
| 2022-03-21 | Advertiser AT | 19 | 0 | 0 | 50 | 1 |
| 2022-03-23 | Advertiser AT | 31 | 0 | 0 | 47 | 0 |
| 2022-03-23 | Advertiser DE | 53 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-03-14 | Advertiser DE | 74 | 16 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-03-10 | Advertiser DE | 85 | 21 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-03-16 | Advertiser DE | 73 | 21 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-03-21 | Advertiser DE | 41 | 23 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-03-19 | Advertiser DE | 125 | 24 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-03-11 | Advertiser DE | 133 | 25 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-03-22 | Advertiser DE | 65 | 25 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-03-09 | Advertiser DE | 121 | 31 | 2 | 0 | 0 |

**Desired Outcome:**

| Advertiser | Conversion | Total Conversions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Advertiser AT | Conversion 1 | 0 |
| Advertiser AT | Conversion 2 | 0 |
| Advertiser AT | Conversion 3 | 354 |
| Advertiser AT | Conversion 4 | 2 |
| Advertiser DE | Conversion 1 | 186 |
| Advertiser DE | Conversion 2 | 3 |
| Advertiser DE | Conversion 3 | 0 |
| Advertiser DE | Conversion 4 | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with the unpivot functionality, see the code below:

```
select advertiser, conversion, sum(total_conversions)
from sample_data
UNPIVOT (total_conversions for conversion in (conversion_1, conversion_2, conversion_3, conversion_4))
group by advertiser, conversion
```

with your data this results in:
[image]